# I need GNU make to create 2 target files and optionally execute a specific target

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
DATA_DIR = ../support/flash_data
SRC = $(DATA_DIR)/flash_data.flash

flash_data.flash: config.mk
    cp $(SRC) $@

flash_data1.flash: config.mk
    cp $(SRC) $@

test:
    @echo --- test
```

I expected that 'make' would produce two files (flash_data.flash and flash_data1.flash) and 'make test' would produce the 2 files and the message.

Also, if config.mk changes, the files should be regenerated when 'make test' is entered.

But if I 'make test' I only get the message and if I just 'make', only flash_data.flash gets created.

What have I missed?

Comment: If you don't specify a target on the make command line, make builds just the first target in the makefile.  See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html

Comment: A common convention is to create an `all:` target as the first target in the makefile, which lists the other targets you want to be built by default as prerequisites.

Comment: Note that the `all:` target should be marked as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: `test` doesnt depend on any of the other rules, so `make test` is not going to trigger them

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I updated the dependencies and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The final version looks like:

```
test: flash_data.flash
    @echo --- test
    cat flash_data.flash > lix

flash_data.flash: config.mk
    cp $(SRC) $@
    python update_flash_data.py 1 2 3 4 5 --output $@
```

'make test' does what it was supposed to be done...
Thanks...